# Why does a .net app launch a "preparing to install" dialog when clicking the shortcut?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

We have a suite of .Net applications that we built installers for with WiX. All of them create shortcuts to the desktop and a few of them have custom icons for the desktop shortcut. When launching the app from the shortcut for the first time the apps with the custom icons launch a "Preparing to install" dialog box before running. I'm thinking this is caused by the custom icon. But I can't pinpoint where the error is coming from. Has anyone else run into this error before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of Windows Installer called "Resiliency".  You have an advertised shortcut that points to the keyfile of a component that belongs to a feature.  There are other components in that features and they have keyfiles also.   Windows Installer is doing a health check when you click on the shortcut and it's deciding there is a problem.

You'll need to look at Event Viewer to get the Component ID triggering the repair and then figure out what is wrong with your installer.

A simple work around would be to not use advertised shortcuts.

Comment: If I delete the Advertised property and there is a problem, will the application crash?

Comment: Hard to say. For example it could be some critical dependency or it could be an assembly that's lit up optionally via reflection.  Windows Installer has no way of knowing that, it just knows it's been told the resource is a key path.